# More than one htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having some trouble understanding .htaccess basically I'm trying to have more than one rewrite rule; for example I have a profile page and then I also want to rewrite the index page so how would this be done; in my previous attempts I could only use one rewrite rule perhaps I was doing something wrong; I have a profile page with the link `/profile/profile.php?user=$username` and the index page `account.php?page=featured` how could I get the profile page to look like `/account/$username` and the account page to look like `/account/featured` thankyou also how would I then add more later down the line?

*the account.php file is in the root directory.*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /tag/index.php?hash=$1&cat=$2
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 Denied
```

that is my current .htaccess which uses the hashtags and shows them like this `/tag/$hashtag` when I tried to copy and paste this to then use under it it didn't work.

Comment: Post Your Current Code

Comment: @ImmortalDude have done :3

Comment: Apache won't be able to tell which file it would need to be rewritten to. Perhaps swap out `/account/username` with `/profile/username` and write the rules to keep them separate. Or, even better, `/account/username/profile`.

Comment: @MikeRockett yeah thats true is it possible you could provide me with an example of using to rewrite rules because at the moment I can only use one as I'm unsure how to use two at the same time.

Comment: Create the rules for each one, and append the `[L]` flag to each one. Will answer with the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, Apache won't be able to tell which file to rewrite to. So you'll need to change one of the URI structures. As a recommendation, change the one for the profiles.

Here is an example to show you how to do this:

```bash
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /tag/index.php?hash=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^account/([^/]+) /account.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+) /profile/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Remember the `[L]` flag, which causes rewriting to stop when a match is found.

Comment: Perfect answer thank you so much very useful, Great Response